# Touch screen on Debian Stretch (KDE) responds on wrong coordinates

Tags: debian, kde, vmware, x-server, touch-screen

I have Dell XPS 15 9530. In it, I had a Debian Jessie virtual machine (vmware) inside a Windows 10 host. The touch screen was working fine.

After upgrading to Debian Stretch, the touch screen doesn't work properly anymore. The mouse position doesn't match the touch position. How can I tackle this problem? I don't even know where to start.

I'm using SDDM as an xserver manager and KDE Plasma.

EDIT:

I found out that if I connect the touch screen to the guest machine as a USB device (and consequently, disconnect it from the host), it works fine. While this "works", it's horrible, because every time I have to switch from host to guest or vice versa, I have to switch that option and deal with drivers in Linux.

Comment: I found that touch-screen is not properly mapped to the display coordinates: open `Displays` and make sure your touchscreen is mapped at 0x0 coordinates, this way it works. This is a work-around, as it don't solve the case of having several touchscreen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, make sure that VMWare is properly emulating the pointing device as a touchscreen or tablet.  I'm not well versed with VMWare, so I'm not 100% certain how to do this myself, but it should be an option somewhere in the configuration.  In most cases, not emulating the right pointing device is the cause of stuff like this.

If VMWare is emulating the correct pointing device, check to make sure that the VMWare extensions in the VM are up to date.

If both of the above items aren't the issue, try `xinput-calibrator`.  You will have to install this package yourself probably, but once you do the included documentation (`man xinput-calibrator` in a terminal) should cover what's needed to use it to correct the offset.

Comment: If VMware was the problem, it wouldn't have worked with Jessie, right?
 I made sure that vmware-tools are installed. The shared folders are working.`xinput-calibrator` says "Error: No calibratable devices found.". Would you know the cause?

Comment: I've seen odd behaviors in a wide variety of VM software that depend on what's running inside the VM itself.  Usually this ends up being related to the tools in the guest itself, but not always.  Also, if you check the output of `xinput -list` run from a terminal emulator in a graphical session, that should either list something about a VMMouse or a touch interface.  If it doesn't, then it's an issue in how VMWare is emulating the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If cursor is still following your finger, [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/890629)  issue can point you in the right direction(it's the opposite, I know).
I had the same problem in with Gnome years ago, and actually found a setting that made me choose the type of pointing input.